# How to trigger keypress event with Class name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, keypress

I am trying to trigger a keypress event when click left mouse button in an input tag with class name.
I can do with id but I don't know how to trigger with class name.
How can I solve this?

I wanna trigger a keypress with class name.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" class="yourClassName" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)" />
    <script>
        function handleKeyPress(event) {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                console.log(event.target.value);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "click" event and button code 0 for left press.

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class-name"); //or use query selector

for(const element of elements) {
  element.addEventListener("click", handleLeftClick);
}

function handleLeftClick(e) {
  if(e.button ===0) {
    //perform action
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger keypress event using a class name you can use `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
let input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
input[0].addEventListener("keypress", function() { alert("the key is pressed") });
```